# Why does the root entry in an exception stack differ depending on context?

Tags: node.js

It's my understanding that all code in a (unclustered) nodejs program runs in the same thread. Given that, I'd expect that all such code would run as a child of the same root event loop, and thus that if one examined the stack traces for code running in different callbacks, we'd still eventually backtrace to the same entry (the "dispatch event" line) of that event loop. But that's not the case, and I don't understand why.

Consider the following:

```
function printStackTrace() {
    console.log(new Error().stack);
}

printStackTrace();
setTimeout(printStackTrace, 1000);
```

running that yields:

```
Error
    at printStackTrace (/tmp/node/test.js:4:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/tmp/node/test.js:7:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:446:26)
    at Object..js (module.js:464:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:353:32)
    at Function._load (module.js:311:12)
    at Array.0 (module.js:484:10)
    at EventEmitter._tickCallback (node.js:190:39)
Error
    at Object.printStackTrace [as _onTimeout] (/tmp/node/test.js:4:17)
    at Timer.ontimeout (timers.js:94:19)
```

and simply running `console.log(new Error().stack);` in the REPL gives a different root still:

```
Error
    at repl:1:13
    at REPLServer.eval (repl.js:80:21)
    at repl.js:190:20
    at REPLServer.eval (repl.js:87:5)
    at Interface.<anonymous> (repl.js:182:12)
    at Interface.emit (events.js:67:17)
    at Interface._onLine (readline.js:162:10)
    at Interface._line (readline.js:426:8)
    at Interface._ttyWrite (readline.js:603:14)
    at ReadStream.<anonymous> (readline.js:82:12)
```

So the root (bottommost) item on each is different (in EventEmitter, Timer, and ReadStream respectively).  It's the same for other callbacks (e.g. net).

So I imagine that either

- the event loop is native (C++) code, so it doesn't show up in the stack trace, and fundamental providers of asynchronous services (repl.js, timers.js, etc.) register themselves with it using a native v8 api call.
- the event loop is JavaScript, but `Error()` has special code to hide this (as an unnecessary implementation detail)

Which (if either) of these is the case, and in general where in the nodejs (edit: or v8) source can I read the implementation of the real root event loop?

Comment: You may want to send a link to this question to the #node.js channel on freenode IRC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer (or at least a clue) is right there in the stack trace.  Just follow the code in the file on the bottom of the stack.

I'm not sure exactly what version of node you're using (0.6?  time to update!), but in the latest (0.10.17),

```
setTimeout(function() { console.log(new Error().stack) }, 1);
```

Prints out:

```
Error
    at null._onTimeout (repl:1:38)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout [as ontimeout] (timers.js:110:15)
```

So let's go to [timers.js:110](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/v0.10.17/lib/timers.js#L110).  This line lives inside the `listOnTimeout` function, which is assigned to the `ontimeout` property of a `Timer` instance.

A [`Timer` is a C++ module](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/v0.10.17/src/timer_wrap.cc) that [interfaces](http://nikhilm.github.io/uvbook/utilities.html#timers) with libuv; it is C++ code that [invokes](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/v0.10.17/src/timer_wrap.cc#L163) the `ontimeout` function.

So there's your answer: the root of the stack is the JavaScript function that was invoked by C++ code (whether the timer or stream plumbing).

The stack trace provided to you by `Error` doesn't show you any native code involved in invoking a function.  The event loop itself is implemented by V8 (native code), not JavaScript, so it should make sense that you don't see anything beyond that boundary.

So what's happening is very close to your first guess.  JavaScript code registers a callback by setting some property to a function (or passing the function as a argument in a call *to* native code).  When C++ wants to invoke that function, it gets the reference and instructs V8 to invoke the function by calling [`v8::Function::Call`](http://izs.me/v8-docs/classv8_1_1Function.html).

If you're interested in how V8 works, the [embedder's guide](https://developers.google.com/v8/embed) is a good start.